# How can i search for multiple "values" in my search box in SSRS REPORT

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, search-box, ssrs-2019

I've created a dropdown list that is filtered according the value present in a search box. However I can only search by one field and I want to search for more than one.

I used this query to make possible to use the search box

```
where upper(ds_in) LIKE upper('%'+@Psearch+'%') or ISNULL(LEN(@Psearch),0)=0
```

But it only allows me to search for one value and I want to shearch for more.
Like imagine you are looking for two countries :

Search box: `ITALY`, `SPAIN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your parameter is a simple comma separated list of values then you can use `string_split()` and then join to the results.

Using your country list as an exmaple...

```
DECLARE @PSearch varchar(max) = 'Italy , spa'

SELECT * FROM myCountryTable c 
    JOIN string_split(@PSearch, ',') s 
        ON c.myCountryName like '%' + LTRIM(RTRIM(s.value)) + '%'
```

This will return anything matching `%Italy%` or `%spa%`

Comment: Thank you @AlanSchofield, i think its working.